# Problem with routes in Nextjs 13.4 - tailAdmin ui

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

i used https://github.com/TailAdmin/free-nextjs-admin-dashboard.

I can't acces to my new blog page (404 error)

"/**app**/blog/[id].tsx"

> ```
> import React from "react";
>
> function Post({ postData }) {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <h1>Post ID: {postData.id}</h1>
>       <p>Post Content: {postData.content}</p>
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> export async function getStaticPaths() {
>   const paths = [{ params: { id: "1" } }, { params: { id: "2" } }];
>
>   return {
>     paths,
>     fallback: true,
>   };
> }
>
> export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
>   const postData = { id: params.id, content: `Content for post ${params.id}` };
>
>   return {
>     props: {
>       postData,
>     },
>   };
> }
>
> export default Post;
> ```

i tested the same code with another project, it work.
(under '/**pages**/blog/[id].tsx')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest reading the [official documentation about dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) since there were groundbreaking changes with next 13.4 (they introduced the app router, which is "quite particular")